# chrome empty network tab when writing local code

Tags: java, html, css, google-chrome

Whenever I go to Network tab on Chrome, it's empty when I type the code on my computer, but it loads files whenever I load some web page.
For example, when I try to get my CSS file using network tab in chrome, it's empty there, but it says 0/3 requests.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nd3HY.png

Answer (score 0):

This has been a problem for me more than four months, and I just clicked "filters" and "Media" was selected, I just had to select "All".
Sorry for a pointless question.